# jQuery plugins conflict with colorbox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, colorbox

I have a page with records using `jQuery Pagination`. Also i used `jQuery Colorbox` plugin for popup. Its working fine in the record first page but when i click next page option in my pagination then the color box popup stopped working. First page have 10 records and the popup working only for those 10 records even if you choose 100/page from option. For testing purpose I upload it online.

```
DEMO : http://aslobi.com/demo/index.php
```

So far I understand the point that the conflict occur when i bring the following 3 js files at the bottom of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dynamic-table.js"></script>
```

When I put it before colorbox js file then popup working only for 1st 10 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the DataTables plugin and while using pagination only the visible items exist in the DOM [[1]](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html). So when you initialize the colorbox, this works only for the first 10 rows in your table.

You need to initialize again the colorbox each time you go to the next or previous page. I checked a bit the DataTables page but I didn't find a callback event for when the page changes. As an alternative I thought to use the `fnRowCallback` callback to initialize the colorbox for every row.

**EDIT**: So, the initialization of the `table#sample_1` would be:

```
$('#sample_1').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sPrevious": "Prev",
            "sNext": "Next"
        }
    },
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        'bSortable': false,
        'aTargets': [0]
    }],
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        jQuery(nRow).colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });
    }
});
```

Comment: you are a great man. Thank you sooooo much, i was really stuck with the colorbox and i was thinking to replace it with another popup plugin :)